# Animate a line between two points - swift

Tags: swift, xcode, cgpoint

I have a class called CategoryCell which us UICollectionViewCell.

On the CellForItemAt function:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

drawfunction.draw_Footing(withView: cell.view)
```

the drawing will be in the cell.view.

draw_Footing functions is a function to draw some lines, and it is located in drawfunction class which it NSObject.
in the same class, I have the function call animateShape which can animate a single line between two points (CGpoint).

```
    func animateShape(view: UIView, p1: CGpoint, p2: CGPoint) {
        
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.removeFromSuperlayer()
                
            // create whatever path you want
        shapeLayer.fillColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0).cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = color.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = linewidth//CGFloat(1.5)
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
                
            // animate it
        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.duration = duration//0.5
        shapeLayer.add(animation, forKey: "MyAnimation")

}
```

I have 4 points G1, G2, G3, G4.
I need to animate a line between these 4 points.
So, if I do:

```
animateShape(view, p1: G1, p2: G2)
animateShape(view, p1: G2, p2: G3)
animateShape(view, p1: G3, p2: G4)
```

All the line will be animated in the same time.
I need to animate first the line between G1 and G2, and after completion, need to animate the line between G2 and G3 and not in the same time.
I tried to include dispatchQueue, but I am not sure and I don't know how.

Any advise?

Comment: Please add more information on your architecture. For example, you have some class which is an NSObject, then you seem to have a View and this View is on a view controller. You don't need to add all the code of the view, view controller and NSObject subclass but atleast getting a picture will help us recommend the best answer because this depends on how and when the animations should start

Comment: I edited again just to explain more about my case, I hope that i tried to explain well the issue

Comment: Yes, this is much more clearer now .. thanks for the update !

Comment: Why can't you make a single path with all four points, and animate the strokeEnd of that?

Comment: If make a single path, it will work fine, but when I have lets say 10 paths, then I need to repeat the same code, so therefore I thought about doing one function to do the animation for any array which contain points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The things is, I do not see how the `path` was actually created using your points `p1` and `p2`

Anyways, I am assuming your end goal is to do a drawing line path animation in a `UICollectionViewCell` and that is what I tried to achieve based on the given the description in your question.

First the drawing class:

```
class DrawFunction: NSObject
{
    weak var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer?
    
    // Change as you wish
    let duration = 2.0
    
    // Responsible for drawing the lines from any number of points
    func drawFooting(points: [CGPoint])
    {
        guard !points.isEmpty else { return }
        
        // Remove old drawings
        shapeLayer?.removeFromSuperlayer()
        
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        
        // This is actual drawing path using the points
        // I don't see this in your code
        for (index, point) in points.enumerated()
        {
            // first pair of points
            if index == 0
            {
                // Move to the starting point
                path.move(to: point)
                continue
            }
            
            // Draw a line from the previous point to the current
            path.addLine(to: point)
        }
        
        // Create a shape layer to visualize the path
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = randomColor().cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5
        shapeLayer.path = path.cgPath
        
        self.shapeLayer = shapeLayer
    }
    
    // Animate function to be called after shape has been drawn
    // by specifying the view to show this animation in
    func animateShape(in view: UIView)
    {
        if let shapeLayer = shapeLayer
        {
            view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
            let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
            animation.fromValue = 0
            animation.duration = duration
            shapeLayer.add(animation, forKey: "MyAnimation")
        }
    }
    
    // You can ignore this function, just for convenience
    private func randomColor() -> UIColor
    {
        let red = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256)) / 255.0
        let blue = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256)) / 255.0
        let green = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256)) / 255.0
        
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Then basic custom cell set up, nothing fancy, just added for completeness

```
// Basic Cell, nothing unique here
class CategoryCell: UICollectionViewCell
{
    static let identifier = "cell"
    
    override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        configure()
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder)
    {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    private func configure()
    {
        contentView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        contentView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        contentView.clipsToBounds = true
    }
}
```

The view controller set up where the most interesting parts are in the `willDisplay cell` function

```
class LineAnimateVC: UICollectionViewController
{
    // Random points to draw lines
    let points = [[CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 10),
                   CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX, y: 10),
                   CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX, y: 50)],
                  
                  [CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 10),
                   CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX, y: 10),
                   CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX, y: 50),
                   CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxX, y: 50)],
                  
                  [CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 10),
                   CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX, y: 10),
                   CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX, y: 50),
                   CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX + 40, y: 50),
                   CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX + 40, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY),
                   CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxX, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY)],
                  
                  [CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 10),
                   CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX, y: 10),
                   CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX, y: 50)],
                  
                  [CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 10),
                   CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX, y: 10),
                   CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX, y: 50),
                   CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX + 40, y: 50),
                   CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX + 40, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY),
                   CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxX, y: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY)]
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        title = "Line animate"
        
        collectionView.register(CategoryCell.self,
                                forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CategoryCell.identifier)
        
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
    }
    
    // Number of cells equals to points we have
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                 numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return points.count
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                 cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CategoryCell.identifier,
                                                      for: indexPath) as! CategoryCell
        
        return cell
    }
    
    // Add animation when cell is about to be displayed
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                                 willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell,
                                 forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        let cell = cell as! CategoryCell
        
        // Draw the path and perform the animation
        let drawingFunction = DrawFunction()
        drawingFunction.drawFooting(points: points[indexPath.row])
        drawingFunction.animateShape(in: cell.contentView)
    }
}
```

Just for completeness, my flow layout set up

```
// Basic set up stuff
extension LineAnimateVC: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize
    {
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 300)
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat
    {
        return 20
    }
}
```

This gives me an animated path in the collectionview cell

[image: Draw Path Line Animation UICollectionView UICollectionViewCell CAShapeLayer UIBezierPath CABasicAnimation Animate line between two points CGPoint]

Hope this gives you some ideas to achieve your task

**Update**

Based on OP, Xin Lok's comment:

> However still did not get what I want, lets say I have path1 =
> [p1,p2,p3,p4,p5] and path2 = [m1,m2,m3], if I run drawFooting(points:
> path1) and drawFooting(path2), both of the 2 paths will be animated in
> the same time , and this what I don't want, I need to complete
> animation for Path1, and then after finish to proceed with animation
> of Path2. I tried to insert sleep, but it did not work

Based on that comment, One way I can think of achieving that is to I think the key is to **reuse and persist** with the shape layer and the path.

Here are some updates I made based on that conclusion

First I just made a simple struct so we can create lines easily

```
struct Line
{
    var points: [CGPoint] = []
    
    init(_ points: [CGPoint])
    {
        self.points = points
    }
}
```

Then I create some random lines and grouped them in an array

```
// Random lines
// Random lines
let line1 = Line([CGPoint(x: 0, y: 10),
                  CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX, y: 10)])

let line2 = Line([CGPoint(x: 0, y: 70),
                  CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX, y: 70),
                  CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX, y: 100)])

let line3 = Line([CGPoint(x: 0, y: 150),
                 CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.midX, y: 110),
                 CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxX, y: 190)])

let line4 = Line([CGPoint(x: 0, y: 210),
                  CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxX / 4, y: 235),
                  CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxX * 0.75, y: 220),
                  CGPoint(x: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxX,
                          y: UIScreen.main.bounds.maxY)])

var lineGroups: [[Line]] = []

private func setLines()
{
    // First cell, it should draw lines in the order 3 -> 1 -> 2
    // Second cell, in the order 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1
    lineGroups = [[line3, line1, line2],
                  [line4, line3, line2, line1]]
}
```

Importantly note the line order in each array, because this is the order they will be drawn

In the drawing class, I made some changes to persist the `CAShapeLayer` and `path`

A special mention to **jrturton** in the comments for suggesting `CGMutablePath` and simplifying the path creation.

```
class DrawFunction: NSObject
{
    weak var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer?
    var path: CGMutablePath?
    
    // Change as you wish
    let duration = 5.0
    
    // Responsible for drawing the lines from any number of points
    func drawFooting(line: Line)
    {
        var shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        
        if self.shapeLayer != nil
        {
            shapeLayer = self.shapeLayer!
        }
        
        if path == nil
        {
            path = CGMutablePath()
        }
        
        // Thank you @jrturton for this
        path?.addLines(between: line.points)
        
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = randomColor().cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5
        shapeLayer.path = path
        
        self.shapeLayer = shapeLayer
    }
    
    // Animate function to be called after shape has been drawn
    // by specifying the view to show this animation in
    func animateShape(in view: UIView)
    {
        if let shapeLayer = shapeLayer
        {
            view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
            let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
            animation.fromValue = 0
            animation.duration = duration
            shapeLayer.add(animation, forKey: "MyAnimation")
        }
    }
    
    // You can ignore this function, just for convenience
    private func randomColor() -> UIColor
    {
        let red = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256)) / 255.0
        let blue = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256)) / 255.0
        let green = CGFloat(arc4random_uniform(256)) / 255.0
        
        return UIColor(red: red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}
```

Then some minor changes in the collectionview cell configuration

```
// Number of cells equals to lines we have
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                             numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return lineGroups.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                             cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
{
    let cell
        = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CategoryCell.identifier,
                                                  for: indexPath) as! CategoryCell
    
    return cell
}

// Add animation when cell is about to be displayed
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                             willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell,
                             forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let cell = cell as! CategoryCell
    
    let lines = lineGroups[indexPath.item]
    
    // Draw the path and perform the animation
    let drawingFunction = DrawFunction()
    
    for line in lines
    {
        drawingFunction.drawFooting(line: line)
    }
    
    drawingFunction.animateShape(in: cell.contentView)
}
```

Now again, for convenience, remember the order in which they should be drawn:

```
First cell, it should draw lines in the order 3 -> 1 -> 2
Second cell, in the order 4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1
```

The end result:

[image: Animate a line between two CGPoints swift iOS CAAnimation chaining CAShapeLayer CGMutablePath]

Comment: make a `CGMutablePath()` and then do `addLines(between: points)` to greatly simplify your path creation

Comment: Thanks for the great example, however still did not get what I want,  lets say I have path1 = [p1,p2,p3,p4,p5] and path2 = [m1,m2,m3], if I run drawFooting(points: path1) and drawFooting(path2), both of the 2 paths will be animated in the same time , and this what I don't want, I need to complete animation for Path1, and then after finish to proceed with animation of Path2. I tried to insert sleep, but it did not work

Comment: @XinLok - please see my updated answer

Comment: @jrturton - thanks for a wonderful suggestion, never knew about `CGMutablePath()` and definately simplified the path creation.

Comment: Thank you very much, god bless you